# Convert 4-digit year to a 2-digit year

Tags: c

I want to get the last 2 digits of a year. For instance, if I started with an input value "2012" I would want to generate an output value of "12".

Is they any option in `fprintf` in which it will print the last two digits only?

Answer (score 6):

Just print the number modulo 100:

```
printf("%2d\n", 2012 % 100);
```

will print `12`.

Comment: Or, in Fortran, to disprove OP's statement that *In Fortran we can't write the number in the desired format* `write(*,'(i2.2)') mod(2012,100)`

Answer (score 3):

Steve314 idea (now deleted) is good but not correctly presented.  Example : if the year was 2009, to use "%2d" to get "09" is not correct.  "%2d" will get you " 9".  "%02d" will get you "09".

```
printf("%02d\n", year % 100);
```

Also there are issues with negative numbers.  %d, %2d, %02d for (-99) will all result in a 3 character answer.  If the year is known to be unsigned, recommend using 'u' instead of 'd'.  If the year is signed could be negative, you may need additional code for this esoteric situation.

Comment: Good catch - I've been using C++ for too long I'm afraid. On `%` with signed integers - it's an annoying issue. In mathematics, a remainder can be negative (depending how you round division) but a modulo cannot. We have one operator and it doesn't decide which job it's doing - a platform *may* always give non-negative results or it may not. Ada has two operators - `mod` and `rem` - and although it's the one I always remember, it's not the only one to do this.

Comment: `%2d` will get you `2012`, not `9`. The number is a minimum field width, not a limit.

Comment: @Matt McNabb The deleted Steve314 comment suggested something like `printf("%2d\n", year % 100);`.  My answer was dealing with the case if `year` was just over a multiple of 100 as in `printf("%2d\n", 2009 % 100);` which would print "9".  By adding the `"0"` to the format, code insures getting 2 digits as OP requests unlike the top rated answer.  Answer updated for greater clarity.   The 2 in `"%2d"` is a minimum _field_ width, but not a minimum number of digits.