# Output 4 digit year from 2 digit input

Tags: c++, input, output

This is part of a code I'm writing.

If à user enters year as 2 digits ( '94 ), it outputs the year as 4 digits { 1994 )

I came across question that requires the reverse of what I need: [Convert 4-digit year to a 2-digit year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698213/convert-4-digit-year-to-a-2-digit-year?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Part of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
     Int yr;

    cout<<"Enter year: " <<endl;
    cin>>yr;

    cout<<"The year is "<<yr<<endl;

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: How will you determine whether "40" is 1940 or 2040?

Comment: Just print `"The year is 19"`

Comment: This is just addition.  You either need to add `1900` or `2000` or whatever `nn00` to the 2 digit part.

Comment: For now, It only caters for past years not the future

Comment: 2012 is a past year, but so is 1912. If a user enters a two digit date *tell them to enter a four digit one* unless they were legitimately born in 12CE.

Comment: Hmm, noted. I have to revise it.

Comment: How do you then run that request for 4 digit year if they enter 2?

Comment: Assuming a one or two-digit year (values `0` to `99`) a simple solution is `year += 1900 + ((year + 2000) <= this_year)*100`, where `this_year` (at the time I write this) is `2018`.   I leave the problem of working out `this_year` from the current date (which will change) as an exercise.

Comment: Alright, let me try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This arose frequently when people were doing y2k conversions in the late 1990s.

One common implementation was to choose, say, 1950 as the cutoff, so `51` through `99` were taken as `1951` through `1999`, and `00` through `50` were taken as `2000` through `2050`.

Comment: Interesting, makes my life easier. Thank you, I'll try this also